# Can you let someone else use your boarding pass to get into a travel lounge?

Tags: airports, united-airlines, lounges

Let's say I was traveling with a friend. My friend is flying economy whilst I'm flying first class. Could I visit the lounge, get the food and all that jazz, then exit the lounge, give my boarding pass to my friend and let them check the lounge out to see what the lounge life is all about?

Comment: “Can you” in what sense? Are you asking whether if it’s within the rules of airline lounge use (any airline or a specific one? They all have slightly different rules). Or are you asking do you will get away with breaking the rules?

Comment: @MJeffryes - the former, altho a good answer would probably address both interpretations. I did include the airline in question as a tag but if an answer discussed other airlines as well that might make for an even better answer!

Comment: Given the security stance surrounding air travel nowadays, I'm not sure if I'd even let anyone else *look* at my boarding pass.

Comment: Also, "the lounge life"... There are a few notable exceptions, but most lounges are just terrible.

Comment: Have you considered that they might call security if they detect an unauthorized person inside the lounge or trying to enter?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In some cases, **your status may allow you to bring in one or more guests**. This is very specific to each airline/program and the various levels, though, so you'll have to check the details for your own loyalty program.

[This page](https://www.godsavethepoints.com/question-can-bring-guests-airport-vip-lounges/) gives some general rules. They say that access via your travel class (business, first...) usually doesn't allow you to bring in a guest. On the other hand, most programs (but not all) allow you to bring a guest if you get access through your frequent flyer status, with a few conditions and exceptions, though. So, again, check the specifics for your combination of frequent flyer program / status / airline / type of flight (domestic or international) / class of travel.

Note that the number of guests is usually limited. Even as a Flying Blue Platinum member, I can't (or couldn't the last time I tried) bring more than one person in a lounge, for instance.

However, **giving your boarding pass to someone else so they can enter without you is most probably a breach of the terms and conditions of the program**.

Comment: +1 I frequently am brought into airline lounges as a guest of one of my friends who travels constantly for work so has all the perks on lock.  You should ask before coming up with weird schemes. They definitely won't want you handing your pass to someone, and if you go in and out and then send someone in with the same pass they're quite likely to notice.

Answer (score 9):

In recent years, I have encountered with all major airlines that they want to see your boarding pass and a valid ID.
As a consequence, you can of course walk out and in as often as you like, but someone else with your boarding pass (and ID!) will have trouble if he doesn't look a lot like you.

It is also a clear violation, and if caught, you will not only lose your access right, but also potentially be disqualified from their frequent flier club, losing any miles already collected.

As others mentioned, depending on airline and status you might be allowed to bring a guest, but they have started to be a lot less generous there too - *just because you are Platinum Select member with an international business class flight doesn't mean you can bring your wife (with an economy boarding ticket) for free*

Comment: Really? Which lounge?  I don't think I have ever in my life been requested to show ID at a lounge, they just ask for the boarding pass.

Comment: @lambshaanxy FRA, MUC, DXB, BOM, PTY (all in 2019)

Comment: @Aganju for what airline / alliance / lounge? I would be surprised if they all applied the same policies.

Comment: I don't think any airport lounge has ever asked for my ID, so I'd say this is definitely a YMMV situation. On the other hand, I'd definitely not recommend attempting to let someone else 'borrow' your boarding pass to access a lounge. Agreed completely with the second paragraph. This is a good way to lose your status and miles and be banned from a frequent flyer program.

Comment: @Aganju I've been using the Lufthansa MUC lounge quite a lot and I've never been asked for an ID. This is a bit surprising for me too.

Comment: Maybe I look too terroristic? I typically don't travel in business attire (as I travel farther, not just within the country)

Answer (score 5):

Legally no, but often there is just a check of the ticket (and a scan of ticket, so that you may enter only once).

You might be able to pay an entry fee (maybe with a discount because of your eligibility). It is said that it is cheaper than staying in the "normal areas": you have less time to wait near boutiques and restaurants, so possibly less expenses.

Comment: "Legally" is probably a bit too strong (unless you classify that as "fraud"). Probably more like "Contractually".

Comment: And I've actually often wondered if one was able to enter/exit lounges several times. I've never had the opportunity to try, and this may depend on the actual lounge and/or program, but this is probably a topic for a new question...

Comment: @jcaron I’ve done that under several programs at different locations - left to shop and reentered, or moved to a different lounge location.  Had no issues with British Airways, Cathay, Emirates or a number of others.

Comment: @jcaron - I've been able to do to the same thing with United. Enter the lounge, leave and re-enter (I had to buy a replacement power cable)

Comment: To say it is cheaper than staying in the normal areas is a rather bizarre interpretation of cheaper.  Surely this must be tongue-in-cheek?

Comment: @gerrit: no. I read somewhere about it. Average passenger spend 50/60 dollars airside (LHR/AMS/ZRH: so the very commercial driven airports) [average, not median]. if you go to a lounge, you may skip most of boring period which can drive you to spend] [OTOH there are many perfume and luxury shops, so most of passengers will spend much much less then the average]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Median spend may be more meaningful than average spend.

Comment: @jcaron It definitely does depend on airline, but I've done it lots of times with Delta. On the other hand, I have been to some lounges where they issue you an access coupon when you check-in for the flight, which is then collected when you're admitted to the lounge or where they stamp your boarding pass so that it can't be used to enter a lounge again. I think the only lounges where I've had that happen were contract lounges rather than ones actually operated by an airline itself, though.

Comment: I've gone into every United lounge and a few other partners in an airport during long layovers. It's fun. I always chatted and told them I wanted to see new areas. No one cared (although the united lounges did get uppity when I had a bunch of people come in as guests).

Comment: @jcaron If the person with the borrowed boarding pass wouldn't have been permitted into the lounge by telling the truth, then it is fraud, under the definition of fraud that's used in most jurisdictions, which can be paraphrased as "getting value through falsehood to which you would not have otherwise been entitled". So, yes, it can be/is a criminal issue, rather than just civil/contractual. It's not clear anyone would prosecute, but they could.

Answer (score 4):

Could you? Yes. Should you? No.

Better for you to load up on snacks in your bag, get a drink in a red cup/fill a bottle, and leave.

I flew 100k a year until recently and regularly brought doggie bags out. I also got to take guests, and would grab total strangers for fun. Sometimes it was good, sometimes they thought I was a creep. To each their own.

Edit: I'm just going to leave this here: If you hand your ticket to your friend, they go into the lounge- what ticket do you have? Your friends? If the TSA stop and decide to search you or your friend, what ID are you going to show? Is it reasonable to explain you traded tickets so your buddy can get into a lounge? Sure- TSA or the police might not blink, but they are going to pull them out to look and be sure. Just not worth it for a cheap brownie. However the Sushi in Japan on the other hand...

Answer (score 3):

SAS doesn't check IDs, they use automated gates where you scan your boarding pass or passport and you can enter and exit how many times you like.

Comment: Did you mean boarding pass, not passport?

Comment: @lambshaanxy they support biometric passports too.